# two contact listeners? (iOS, cocos2d, box2d)

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I am develop game using cocos2d and box2d.This game have some similarity with angry birds (not so much, but i hope it helps me to explain my question). I have special objects that I throwing (like birds) in other objects (rocks,wood, glass etc). Some special objects have special properties, and when I choose them I need to know when the first contact occurred. For example I choose the bomb, throw it, and when it contact with other object I have to call explosion method.
My question is: How I can realize this? I understand that in contact listener I can check every contact and if one of the object is bomb - then call explosion method. But I understand that it is wrong way :-)
May be I have to add second contact listener when the bomb chosen, and delete it after explosion? May be I have to use nsnotification or something like this? Help me, please
Thank you!

Comment: using one contact listener is a good way. Why do you think its not?

Comment: thank you for answer! I am new for game development, may be that is the reason :-) I think that if I will check every touch is there are bomb(and some other objects with special properties) or not, cpu will do a lot of unnecessary work (about 5 extra checking if statement at every contact).

Comment: Don't optimise, until you found the bottleneck. Box2d does really a lot work to solve the contacts when they occur. So a few `if` checks will never be noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest next solution: after bomb was thrown, check at every time step its contacts; if some contact is touching, then explode the bomb. How to check contacts of the bomb you can see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17411728/486516).